# problem with postgresql sequence and hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, sequence

I often read this site, but this is the first time I write, hope I won't make mistakes and apologize for my bad english.
I get to the point: I have to develop code to insert records on a single table of a postgresql db, using hibernate on a Springboot project. The table has got a sequence, and I would like to use it to get the id's value.
Into the hbm.xml file of my table I have this:

```
table="td_tito">
        <id name="idTito" column="ID_TITO">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">seq_td_tito</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property ..../>
        <property ..../>
```

In the bean class I have the variable idTito and its getter and setter methods.

When i try to save by calling save method of my class that implements JpaRepository interface, I get the following exception:

```
12:56:06.746 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
```

12:56:06.747 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
12:56:06.756 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
12:56:06.782 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
  Position: 17
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2510)
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2245)
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:311)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:109)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
                at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:95)
                at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
                at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:523)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:179)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
                at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:626)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:619)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:614)
                at com.xxx.hibernate.TestHIbernate.saveTdtito(TestHIbernate.java:122)
                at com.xxx.hibernate.TestHIbernate.main(TestHIbernate.java:20)
12:56:06.782 [main] WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
12:56:06.782 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
  Position: 17

This is the Entity Class:
@Entity
public class TdTito   {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long idTito;
private int lev;
...

public Long getIdTito() {
    return idTito;
}
public void setIdTito(Long idTito) {
    this.idTito = idTito;
}

public int getLev() {
    return lev;
}
public void setLev(int lev) {
    this.lev = lev;
}
```

}

By removing the annotations I get this error as I try to start the Application:

2020-06-16 15:26:46.394 ERROR 23244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.xxx..entities.mappingdb.TdTito
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx..Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.xxx..entities.mappingdb.TdTito
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:781) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted

Any suggestion? Thank you so much to everybody
Step

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace and log the SQL statements (logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug)

Comment: of course, thank you. I just added the complete stack trace

Comment: Could you also show the Entity class? Btw. why are you using XML and not Annotations?

Comment: Just copied the Entity class. I used xml without a real reason...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using you must remove all annotations from the entity

This line is causing the search for hibernate_sequence:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Simply remove this line.

But I recommend to use use annotations. This will look like this:

```
@Id 
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_td_tito", sequenceName = "seq_td_tito")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_td_tito", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long idTito;
```

Comment: unfortunately by removing those lines I had an error while trying to start the application

Comment: And what is the error? And wouldn't you want to move to Annotions instead of the XML?

Comment: I've copied the error  above. To me is OK to move to annotations... Thank you so much, you are kind, I really appreciate

Comment: The problem is now that the XML files are not loaded. You would have to specifiy this. But I would recommend to use Annotation. I updated my answer

Comment: Now it seems to work fine. Thank you a lot, I really appreciate. My best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for sometime, then following combination worked, for the same strategy

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

my `application.properties` has these entries.

```
spring.datasource.username= postgres  
spring.datasource.password= mypassword  
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= org.postgresql.Driver  
spring.jpa.generate-ddl= true  
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update  
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

and `pom.xml` has one dependency as needed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```